# Peewee and Inserts with lists

Tags: python, peewee

I'm confused on how to insert a list of tuples into the db using Peewee. My db is setup as follows:

```
class Stats(Model):
    name = TextField(index=True)
    gender = TextField()
    age = TextField()
    city = TextField()
    state = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

My list of tuples looks like this:

```
records = [("Joe Smoe", "Male", 34, "Joe City", "Joe State")],
          [("Jane Doe", "Female", 21, "Jane City", "Jane State")]
```

Do I iterate over the list inserting one row at a time?  Can this be bulk inserted or does it need to be made into a dict to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* iterate over the list and insert one row at a time, but it's much better and significantly more efficient to use peewee's [Model.insert_many](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.insert_many) function to do a bulk insert with a single SQL `INSERT` statement. And yes, per those API docs, `insert_many()` requires a list (or any iterable) of `dict` objects, each of which must have the same keys.

You can do this manually, like so:

```
rows = [
    {"name": "Joe Smoe", "gender": "Male", "age": 34,
     "city": "Joe City", "state": "Joe State"},
    {"name": "Jane Doe", "gender": "Female", "age": 21,
     "city": "Jane City", "state" :"Jane State"},
    ...
]
Stats.insert_many(rows)
```

Or if you already have a list of `records` tuples like you've shown in your question, you can use `Model._meta.sorted_field_names` to iterate over the `Stats` model's field names to build the dicts:

```
# Be sure to exclude the implicit primary key field
fields = [name for name in Stats._meta.sorted_field_names if name != 'id']
rows = [dict(zip(fields, record)) for record in records]
Stats.insert_many(rows)
```

Comment: Ah that is good info to know.  I actually decided to just convert it to a dict.  I'll post in the answer how I did it, but I'll award you the official answer since you did a spectacular job explaining what I originally wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just taking the individual lists and using dict comp on them to convert them into a dict for insertion.  So it looked something like this:

```
name_list = ['Joe Smoe', 'Jane Doe']
gender_list = ['male', 'female']
age_list = [34, 21]
city_list = ['Joe City', 'Jane City']
state_list = ['Joe State', 'Jane State']

completed_dict = [{
                 'name': a, 'gender': b, 'age': c, 'city': d, 'state': e}
                 for a, b, c, d, e, in zip(name_list, gender_list,  age_list, city_list, state_list)]

with db.atomic():
    Stats.insert_many(completed_dict).execute()
```

Not sure if this was the best way to do it, but it worked just fine for me.